# VBA interpretation of input date

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

I have this annoying date format inconsistency with Excel VBA. I have a source text file, which has dates in format of `dd/mm/yyyy` (i.e. the sane format). But I need to convert it to `yyyy/mm/dd` (for consistency, I also set up this format as default in my computer).

When I export this text file into database, if both of the `dd` and `mm` values are less than 12, VBA treats them as `mm/dd/yyyy` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`. Even I am very confused about this non-standard date format, poor VBA.

For example, I have `06/08/2015` in text file, which is `6th August`, but  `CDate("06/08/2015")` returns `2015/06/08`, i.e. `8th June`. But if the text file has `15/08/201`5, VBA can identify it as `2015/08/15`.

How to tell VBA that `06/08/2015` is in `dd/mm/yyyy` format?

Any help with this annoying and tedious task would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: VBA is biased toward American dates. When using CDate() if a legal date can be formed by mm/dd it will go that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DateSerial() instead of CDate():

```
    Dim d$
    d = "06/08/2015"
    MsgBox DateSerial(Right$(d, 4), Mid$(d, 4, 2), Left$(d, 2))
```

This way you control which bits of the date are which.

Comment: Yes, that's the only way I can see it working, but was hoping for a more generic way, as the data source isn't very consistent either, it could dd/mm one day, and mm/dd the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot for DateSerial hint. That's the way to go for now.

Comment: If the data are not consistent, you are in a tough spot.